# Select a row that matches one condition, or else a row that matches another condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID    A        B       C 
1     'jack'   10      '12'
2     'steve'  0       '20'
3     'jack'   20      '13'
4     'jack'   20      '12 *'
5     'steve'  5       '30 *'
```

Now, I want to select a single row that matches the following conditions:

1. A = @A
2. B = @B
3. In case condition #2 can not be met: C LIKE '%*'

#### Example 1:

```
@A = 'jack'
@B = '10'
```

Rows 1, 3 and 4 match condition #1. Row 1 also matches condition #2, so that row is returned.

#### Example 2:

```
@A = 'steve'
@B = '10'
```

Rows 2 and 5 match condition #1. None of them match condition #2, but row 5 matches condition #3, so that row is returned.

So far, I've got this SQL statement which kind of works:

```
select * from table where A='steve' and (B='10' or C like '%*') limit 1
```

The problem with this solution is that I'm not sure which order `B='10' or C like '%*'` are executed. If they are always executed from left to right, then it will work. But if for some reason that is not always the case, then condition #3 (`C like '%*'`) could be executed before condition #2 (`B='10'`), leading to the wrong row being returned.

How can I make sure that my conditions are always executed in the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering logic in the `where` clause looks fine.

I think the problem you want to solve is how to prioritize the results where there is a match on condition 2 and another on condition 3.

I think that you can solve this with a sort and limit:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where a = 'steve' and (b = '10' or c like '%*') 
order by case when b = '10' then 0 else 1 end
limit 1
```

This prioritizes the row that matches on `b = 10` against a possible match on `c like '%*'`.